# Having trouble passing complex model to controller through ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor

I'm trying to update my model whenever a button is clicked. When I log the data I'm sending in the razor file to the console, the data is all there. However, when the controller method is called, the model is empty.

My onclick method:

```
function addCoupon() {
  var code = document.getElementById("coupon-entry").value;
  $.ajax({ // Validate coupon first. This is working.
    method: "post",
    url: `/cart/validate-coupon/` + code,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  }).done(result => {
    if (result.success) {
      var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
      console.log(model); // Countries and CheckoutData are correct here
      $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: `/cart/add-coupon/` + code,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: model
      }).done(result => {
        console.log("It worked");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

My model:

```
public bool IsPos { get; set; }
public List<CountryDto> Countries { get; set; }
public CheckoutData CheckoutData { get; set; }
public string Payment ProcessorError { get; set; }
public bool DisplayRequiredErrors { get; set; }
public List<string> ValidationErrors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
public PaymentInformationModel PaymentInformation { get; set; } = new PaymentInformationModel();
public bool UseSavedCard { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost("add-coupon/{code}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddCouponAsync(string code, CheckoutModel model)
{
  // Countries and CheckoutData are null here
}
```

There were several similar questions posted on here, but they all either had simple models, or had solutions that didn't work for me when I tried them.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling the mapping of your object on your front end doesn't match what your api contract.  Have you placed a break point inside of your api?   If so can you step through the code.  Do you have validation defined on your model?  Have you tried your api call with an app like postman?  I think it would be useful to compare your api json request from razor to a working postman json request.

Comment: this `/cart/add-coupon + code` would need a / I think like `/cart/add-coupon/ + code`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the / when I was writing this question up. This doesn't work even with the slash. I tried to do this call with Postman, but I got the same thing: an empty model. How do I place a breakpoint in my api? Do you mean inside the controller method?

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing it to this (otherwise it isn't valid javascript):

(Notice that it needs to be encapsulated in '')

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))';
```

Comment: Thanks, but Countries and CheckoutData are still null

Comment: Ok, but the rest of the fields are populated i.e ProcessError,PaymentInformation etc.?

Comment: They're either null or false, but it's difficult to tell since they're supposed to be null or false. The PaymentInformation object is actually passed through, but it's also an empty model.

Comment: Can you pass in a non null/non false value to test?

Comment: I passed in true, but it's showing up as false in my controller. So a blank model must have been created.

Comment: I've just updated my answer as it look like its due to this instead